# How do I build vala from scratch

Tags: gnome, vala

When I try to build vala (https://github.com/gnome/vala), I get an error from autogen that vala must already be installed in order to build vala. So how can I build it on a system that doesn't have it already? I get that it is self hosting, but there has to be some way to boot strap it.

My os is Android-x86 6.x

Answer (score 2):

You can download a [source tarball from download.gnome.org](https://download.gnome.org/sources/vala/) and build from there. The tarballs contain generated C code to build the compiler without a Vala compiler installed.

The procedure would be something like:

```
curl --location https://download.gnome.org/sources/vala/0.38/vala-0.38.4.tar.xz \
     --output vala-0.38.4.tar.xz
tar --extract --file vala-0.38.4.tar.xz
cd vala-0.38.4/
./configure
make
```

The configure script should detect there is no `valac` installed and select the bootstrap option. You could also try `make bootstrap` if you run in to problems.

You can then run the test suite and install to the usual Unix file locations with:

```
make check
make install
```

Although the install part may not be relevant to Android.

Comment: That works. Thanks. I'm muddling through the ./configure. As long as I can meet the dependencies, this should do it!

Comment: Looks like I speak too soon :( I get an error from make: ./build-aux/git-version-gen: No Such File or Directory Makefile:994: recipe for target 'gen-version' failed. It appears to use git to generate a version for something??? I've never seen this before.

Comment: It is the version of Vala. If you build from master and do `valac --version` you will get a "dirty" version number like Vala 0.39.4.12-f8678d. It is that script that uses `git` to find the tag to create the version. In the tarball, however, there should be a file `.tarball-version` that `git-version-gen` finds. Possible things that could be going wrong in the script on Android are the file test is incompatible with the shell, you don't have the `cat` command installed. Another option is to hack the script. Try `cat ../.tarball-version | tr --delete "\n"; exit 0` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks - commenting over the version check worked. But I run into one issue after another. Android just can't provide the tool chain. So I decided to cross compile from Ubuntu. But I am unable to build on Ubuntu either, I run into similar issues. Currently I'm stuck on another Gnome utility 'libtools'. I guess I was expecting a more straightforward build, but this takes so much insider knowledge that it may as well be proprietary. I'm not losing anymore sleep on this, I give up. Normal people can't do this, it takes a gnome :)

Comment: Sure, a tool chain, especially for cross compiling, is a complex thing. It takes time and perseverance to learn. `libtools` is part of Autotools, rather than GNOME. GNOME is switching from using the Autotools build system to Meson. That will hopefully make these things a lot simpler for those new to the process